# How to center this by using css?

Tags: html, css

Original CODE:

```
div class="container body">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
        <div class="bodyhead"><div>
          <h1>We are a Creative Digital Agency</h1></div>
          <div>
        <a href="#"><p class="learn_more">Learn More</p></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
         <img class="laptop" src="/images/laptop.png">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to achieve the following by using CSS only

```
<div><center>
        <a href="#"><p class="learn_more">Learn More</p></a>
          </center></div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: May be this link can help you: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: There is this site ... http://howtocenterincss.com/ ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `text-align` property:

```
text-align: center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/089tnjom/

`<center>` is now deprecated and not supported in HTML 5.

Comment: Hi, yes, i tried to select div, a, or p, they are all not working for me... I mean I'd like the <p> to be centered.

Comment: @Yan - check out the JSFiddle link I provided.  It centres the `p` tag for you.